# How do you right align a horizontal UIStackView?

Tags: swift, interface-builder, uistackview

I've yet to find an answer for this anywhere and I'm not sure if it's possible, but I'm trying to right align a horizontal `UIStackView`, so that if subviews are hidden they move towards the right side not the left. Either programmatically (in Swift) or using the Interface Builder

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`UIStackView`s align according to the user's text direction, i.e. left aligned for English and other Roman script languages, or right aligned for languages such as Hebrew.

In my opinion, changing this for layout reasons may be a misuse of the text direction APIs, and a bit of a hack, but with that in mind:

You can change the direction for a particular view in interface builder, using the Semantic drop down, which has options for 'Force Left-to-Right' and 'Force Right-to-Left', which will change the direction they pop to but also the order they are shown in. So you will have to reverse the order of the elements in your stack view

[image: Semantic selector in IB]

Or you can do it in code, using the view's `semanticContentAttribute`

```
stackView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Comment: Is there any way to change that direction for a specific UIView?

Comment: I updated my answer to cover how you change it for a specific view yesterday, has that helped you?

Answer (score 18):

What worked best for me was putting my horizontal stackview inside a vertical stackview and set the vertical one's alignment to leading

Comment: I think you meant to say 'trailing', not leading. Anyway, this works.

Answer (score 14):

Unlike the other answers, the solution is actually fairly simple. What you need is to add a trailing constraint that pins the stack view to the trailing edge of its superview and then also add a leading constraint that pins it to the leading edge of the superview.

The trick, however, is changing the leading stackview constraint relation from **equal** to **greater than or equal**.

That will allow the leading edge of the stack view to snap over to the intrinsic width of the contents of the stackview, effectively pinning everything to the trailing edge.

Vertical stack views are similar. Pin the top with equals, and pin the bottom with less than or equal.

So:

```
stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: parent.leadingAnchor).isActive = true

stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

stackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
```

Comment: Well done on offering a solution that actually uses things slightly beyond default hacks... That's what those options are for - things like this.

Comment: Saved me after hours of dealing with this issue!

Comment: You might have to add content hugging priority on the inner stackView contents to prevent them stretching to fill the available space and centering whatever they contain.

Answer (score 4):

I had a horizontally oriented `UIStackView` containing two `UIView`s; hiding one of the views led to the other spreading full-width. Adding a width constraint to the remaining view resulted in keeping the desired width, but it shifted to the right.

**TL;DR**

Add a hidden `UIView` to the stack view which shows when the other is hidden for spacing.

Comment: It solves my issue, with this approach your stack view must be configured like:     `stackView.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFill;` & `stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentCenter;`